# Java collision detection with 3d obj models

Tags: java

I was looking around a lot but only found how to check collision for 2d objects.. for my current project I want to check colisions in 3d (I'm using obj models) - I could probably figure out something myself the problem is that I only know the center point of each object..

Is there a way to get the boarders of the object so I can check if it touches the boarders of another object? What would be the best way to get this information?

Edit: Some more information that might help:

I'm using lwjgl 2.8,

my objects are obj files,

I can get position, scale and the rotation of an object

EDIT: This is what I found on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu6nAXFm2Wo&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXm1KEr_2zQ6K_0hoGH6JJ0&index=4

Comment: Are you using any library or framework, or you just want raw code in java? The answer depends greatly of how you are representing your 3d objects.

Comment: well I'm using lwjgl for openGL stuff.. The obj files are just vertex coordinates that make up a mesh.. I don't really know if that's sufficient information, if there's anything else you need to know just tell me..

Comment: Do you have the vertex information for your model, at least? With that, you go through all the vertices and find the min and max for each dimension, and with that you can generate a bounding box, used later for the detection.

Comment: I can always open the obj files with notepad++ and view all vertex corrdinates there.. wouldn't know how to get them in the code though.. I can add my mesh and obj class maybe you would know what to do..?

Comment: I saw that there's some Obj index class in my code (it's from a tutorial) and there's a method GetVertexIndex, could I make something with that? oh and in my objmodel class there's a method that reads the obj file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is called a [triangle soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_soup)[1]: you got vertex position (, texture and normal) information couppled with triangle information. What you can do is intersect each triangle from one mesh with another mesh. You can do this either brute-force (by testing all the other triangles each time) or build up a [space partitioning data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) to speed up your intersections.

E.g. build an [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) per mesh and iterate over the leaves in one of them: for each of those leaves, test its bounding box against the leaves in the other tree and for each of those collision pairs brute-force test each triangles within either of those pairs against each other (or only test those from mesh A against those in mesh B, if you don't care about self-intersections).

There are libraries for these sorts of algorithms like [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org) or [Bullet](http://www.bulletphysics.org/) for example. But I only know of one port to Java: [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/).

EDIT: If you're only interested in approximate collisions you can throw away all information about triangles and build a bounding volume out of your vertices (e.g. an axis aligned box is just the min and the max for all vertex positions, an oriented box is built similarly, but you have to find a good enough orientation first, a sphere is [a bit more involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere) and finally you have a convex mesh, which uses the same sorts of intersection tests as a normal mesh, but is smaller than the original and convex, allowing for some optimisations of the general intersection test).

[1]: there are [other kinds of 3D representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Half-edge_data_structure) that record information about how the triangles are connected. You might imagine finding only two intersecting triangles in mesh A and mesh B and then start searching for intersecting triangles only in the neighbourhood of the initial intersection... these algorithms are much more involved, but for meshes that deform have the advantage, that you don't have to rebuild the space partitioning data structure each time as you have to do with triangle soups.

Comment: thanks, can you point me to some tutorials for this, or give an example yourself because I would definately have not ideo how to code this on my own..?

Comment: @DisasterCoder try JBullet, but welcome also to the hard part of programming: not having quality tutorials on hard algorithms, that's 3d computer graphics in a nutshell ;)

Comment: Oh thanks.. well I found a tutorial that will help me do what I want - it's not hard by the way, you just have to know where to look ;) thanks for your help!

Comment: @DisasterCoder cool, maybe you can link the tutorial in your question for others to find ;)

Comment: Oh yes, it's more a physics tutorial but colision detection is in there too.. here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu6nAXFm2Wo&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXm1KEr_2zQ6K_0hoGH6JJ0&index=4 it's cpp but it will work for java too..